# What is the signature of a PayPal webhook in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

I fail to wrap my head around PayPal webhooks. They offer [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) to create, delete, list webhooks. For instance, when

```
var create_webhook_json = {
    "url": "https://www.yeowza.com/paypal_webhook",
    "event_types": [
        {
            "name": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED"
        },
        {
            "name": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.VOIDED"
        }
    ]
};
```

then I expect `https://www.yeowza.com/paypal_webhook`to be a webhook.

My question about that sample webhook:

1. does it receive events from PayPal when its registered events occur? (obviously yes)
2. does PayPal issue requests of type POST?
3. how can the webhook inspect such an event?
4. what does PayPal expect as an response?

Finally is "webhooks" limited to PayPal or is it a general node.js concept?

Comment: 1,2,3 and 4 read their documentation and your last bit no webhook is a universal buzzword for "when my app does something I'll notify your app via a URL you provide"

Comment: @Darkrum the docs make no sense to me. Given [Webhook event names](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/) I get redirected to [Post requests](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/). Do you mean to say that PayPal sends these to the webhook as if it was a client?

Comment: I went back to the docs and found [Notification messages](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/notification-messages/) which answers 2. (yes POST) and 4 (return a 200). As for 3, I am still puzzled because the docs link events to client calls. Which is confusing.

Comment: Webhook is a general web architecture concept not limited to node.js. Traditionally webhook examples are given in PHP or Java but recently more and more examples use node.js as the language of choice. A webhook simply means a URL that you implement that an external service can send a HTTP request to in order to give you some data. There is no standard for webhooks. You need to read docs of individual services for how they will make the request to your server and what format they will send data as

Answer (score 2):

Darkrum was right when he said that the answer can be found in the docs.

1,2,4: "When an event occurs, PayPal issues an HTTP POST notification message to your app at the webhook listener URL that you defined in your webhook. ... When your app receives the notification message, it must respond with an HTTP 200-level status code. If your app responds with any other status code, PayPal tries to resend the notification message 25 times over the course of three days."

As for 3 you may want to check the [example](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/notifications/webhook-events/webhook_payload_verify.js).

Comment: Should one clone the paypal repo (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) into their project? The example has a var paypal = require('../../../'); at the top. And then, this example code would be in the route, correct?

Answer (score -1):

PayPal REST APIs use webhooks for event notifications. Webhooks are push API calls that let your app know an event has happened.

For creating webhooks login to the paypal developer account and go to ‘My App and Credentials’ menu. In that page you can see your apps which has already added and click on the app and go to details page to add the webhook for your app. To create webhook you have to give url which starts with https:// to get event notifications from paypal. you can select which event type you want to receive notifications.

you can find complete guide to implement webhooks with node js in following link.
**https://techpituwa.wordpress.com/2022/08/24/paypal-webhook-notifications-with-nodejs/**